# Expose method creating a web-component using Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-component

I am creating a web-component using VueJS 3, I want to expose a method on the component allowing the user to do something like this:

```html
  <custom-component id="x1" />

  <script>
    var component = document.getElementById("x1");
    
    component.customMethod(); // as focus() method on native elements
  </script>
```

If I define a method on the component, I can call the method inside the component. But the method is not available when I use it as a web-component.

```
  //main.ts/js
  import { defineCustomElement } from "vue"
  import component from "./component.ce.vue"

  const element = defineCustomElement(component );

  customElements.define("custom-component ", element);
```

```
  //component.ce.vue
  const customMethod = () => { console.log("Executed"); }
```

How I can indicate to Vue Component Wrapper that the customMethod will be available outside the component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `<script setup>`, use the [`defineExpose()` macro](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose):

```html
<script setup>
const customMethod = () => {⋯}
      
defineExpose({ customMethod })
</script>
```

In the `setup()` hook, use the [`expose` property of the `context` argument](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#exposing-public-properties):

```html
<script>
export default {   
  setup(props, { expose }) {
    const customMethod = () => {⋯}
      
    expose({ customMethod })
  }
}
</script>
```

In the Options API, use the [`expose` option](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#expose):

```html
<script>
export default {
     
  expose: ['customMethod'],
  methods: {
    customMethod() {⋯}
  }
}
</script>
```

Currently (as of Vue 3.2.31), the only way to access the custom element's exposed properties is through its `_instance.exposed` property:

```js
<!-- example/index.html -->
<body>
  <custom-component id="x1"></custom-component>
  <script>
    const el = document.getElementById('x1')
                   
    el._instance.exposed.customMethod()
  </script>
</body>
```

Since `_instance` is a private property, use this solution with caution, as the property could be renamed/removed in a future release.

[demo (`<script setup>`)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-expose-props-on-custom-element?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.ce.vue)

[demo (`setup()` hook)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-expose-props-on-custom-element-xtpq4b?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.ce.vue)

[demo (Options API)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-expose-props-on-custom-element-mmsk9u?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.ce.vue)

Comment: As of 3.3.7, accessing `_instance` in a component defined with a `.ce.vue` file that has `defineExpose({ .. })` doesn't work and the methods are not available for calling. -1 for this answer. There is a bug report considered to be a feature request, which is a clear regression from 2.x (https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5540) that is over a year old and nobody is looking into solving the problem.